# Command prompt returns with error when specified a file destination with spaces

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am having some problems executing file having spaces on destination.

My code is:

```
@echo off
start=D:\New folder\Setup To Install.exe
```

As you can see I have many spaces in above path and command processor returns with an error:

```
Can't find the file specified
D:\New
```

`cmd.exe` stops reading path after the space.

And it fails also if I add quotes, i.e. use

```
@echo off
start="D:\New folder\Setup To Install.exe"
```

How to start the executable with spaces in path and file name correct?

Comment: What's the error message in the quoted version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
    "D:\New folder\Setup To Install.exe"
```

Or, if the `start` command is needed

```
@echo off
    start "" "D:\New folder\Setup To Install.exe"
```

`start` command interprets the first quoted string as a window title, the reason for the `""` in the command.

Comment: Can't you just put the command on one line, wrapped in quotes instead of using `start`  For example `"c:\my folder\new folder\file.exe`